# Cannot get Current Webview HTML page path when page changed from Cordova android app

Tags: android, cordova, webview

I am trying to get current html page path from "asset" folder in cordova android app, when we changing the pages inside the cordova webview.

I am using only MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends CordovaActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    loadUrl(launchUrl);
}}
```

I searched and tried my level best to find the solution. But still now I cannot get the right solution. I am totally confused, Please suggest any solution for the followings,

1. Any function available to detect cordova webview URL when page changed
   like **public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
   }** method?
2. Can we create WebViewClient for Cordova Webview?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the current url with

```
appView.getUrl();
```

To get url changes you can use this:

```
SystemWebView wv = (SystemWebView)appView.getView();
wv.setWebViewClient(new SystemWebViewClient((SystemWebViewEngine)appView.getEngine()){
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

        // you can get the current url with view.getUrl()
        // or the url that it's trying to load next with url
        return false;

    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried this, It worked for the first time when initiating the app, but I cannot get the url when changing page from one to another.

Comment: See the edit. You can override the ```shouldOverrideUrlLoading```, or ```onPageFinished``` or ```onPageStarted``` of the ```SystemWebViewClient```

Comment: Not getting the URL in shouldOverRideUrlLoading() at first instance its self. what to do? Please help.

Comment: This works, so if you are not getting it, show your code in a new question